# XMLHttpRequest To get nick value, and privileges value

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

can you please help me to get these values using XMLHttpRequest ? How can I do it using javascript , I am  unable to get them , it write undefined when I try to alert the value of any of these.£ It will help me a lot please ,
Thanks ! I also want the 'privilege values' , thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg5V3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();



xhr.open("GET", "https://brainly.in/api/28/api_users/me", true);

xhr.onload = function () {
    if (this.status === 200){
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var nick = data.data.user.nick;
    var privlage = data.data.user.privileges;
    alert(`The nick is ${nick}  and privileges are ${privlage.join(',')}`  
    }else{
    alert("Failed to load API")
    }    
};

xhr.send(data);
```

Next time post the text version of your JSON instead of an image that way I can be certain about the Objects, but that concept should work

Comment: thanks a lot dear , but how to use variables outsite the request ? is it the role of xhr;send(data); ?

Comment: Can you do it in a tampermonkey version please ?

Comment: If you do it it will really help e please

Comment: look at json please